# How to create a new line in the output (JavaScript Gui)

Tags: javascript, output, newline

For example:

```
Output.setText("Number of Cars = "+cQuantity
        + "Number of Trucks = " +tQuantity
```

How would I have the trucks to go on a separate line in the output on the Gui? Sorry, I am new to coding.

Comment: `\n` is the newline character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When tracing out variables in the console, How to create a new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239474/when-tracing-out-variables-in-the-console-how-to-create-a-new-line)

Comment: This depends entirely on the output context. Is this in an HTML document or a console?

Comment: What does your `setText` function do? Are you sure this isn't a Java question?

Comment: Not only "what does your setText do" but also, What exactly is `Output`?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `\n` escape character, or in ES6 you may use template strings:

```
console.log('Hello \n World');

console.log(`Hello
World`);
```

Both of these will yield the same result:

```
Hello
World
```

If you are planning to output the text to html, you could include a `<br/>` tag:

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML ='Hello<br/>World';
```